# Permission Denied When Trying to Create Python3 Virtual Environment

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, python3, virtualenv

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I'm trying to allow users to create their own virutalenv for python3, however when trying to create said environment using a standard user account with this command:`$ python3 -m venv ~/path/to/venv`

I get this error: 
`Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '~/path/to/venv'`

~/path/to/venv is already created and is owned by the standard user. The permissions are 775. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

try and run `sudo python3 -m venv ~/path/to/venv`.

sudo in Linux environment means super user do which basically means that you are giving a command with super user access.

Comment: I don't want my standard users to need sudo privileges to able to do this. From my reading online, they shouldn't need it right?

Comment: As far as it is known to me, you need admin previleges to create and copy something in root path

Comment: But it's in the users home directory?

Comment: try python3 -m venv /home/mypc....... replace mypc with the name of the your user.

Comment: The problem resolved itself. As both commands work(I'm not entirely sure why). Just for refernce, when "~" (Tilde) is in a path name, it references the users home directory. Ie ~/ == /home/user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem mysteriously resolved itself. Any user is able to create a virtual environment now after no apparent change.